# Is it possible to add an aggregator as a processing step in a routing slip using Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using the routing slip pattern to handle processing my messages through an application that can have multiple processing steps. One of the "steps" that I need to account for is some sort of aggregation prior to processing the remainder of steps.

The processes would look something like this based on a set of rules used to assign an itinerary:

Itinerary 1: Step 1, Step 2, Send e-mail notification, Create case

Itinerary 2: Aggregate everything that qualifies for this rule dynamically, Step 3, Send notification

The problem that I am experiencing is with the camel aggregation. The aggregator requires an endpoint destination to be defined therefore the routing slip can not handle the delivery to the next endpoint that it has defined.

I have a feeling that I may need to build a separate process to handle this aggregation. I was just wondering if anyone has run into a similar issue or has any thoughts about how to handle this within Camel?

UPDATE:

After playing around with these concepts I have noticed that the camel routing slip does indeed process to the next URI, it just does not wait for the aggregation to signal its completion. What we end up with in itinerary 2 is that the itinerary is completed for every qualifying exchange and notifications are sent for every one of those exchanges. What I want is for the routing slip only continue to process that itinerary once aggregation is complete so we have a grouped set of exchanges and one notification sent.

Comment: The camel users group is pretty active, you may check them out [here](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-Users-f465428.html).

Comment: Please post a [ssce](http://sscce.org/) if possible. (e.g. some code, preferably some example code highlighting what you're asking about)